# How to implement secure websocket client in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, node-modules, ws

I want to connect to a secure websocket server(WSS). I am using the following node module:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws
How can I create a secure WebSocket client in node.js.
Is there any way to send certificate while creating websocket client?

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/HEAD/doc/ws.md#new-websocketaddress-protocols-options & https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback & https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tlsconnectoptions-callback `ca` & `cert` properties are your friends.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and could not find it in the ws documentation either. Apparently the tls options can also be used as documented here:
https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tlscreatesecurecontextoptions

When using this example from the docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#round-trip-time and adding a second 'options' parameter:

```js
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://websocket-echo.com/', options);
```

I was able to get client side certificate authentication working using these options:

- "ca": path to CA cert, of buffer with CA cert
- "cert": path to client certificate file or buffer with client cert
- "key": path to client private key used to create the client certificate, or buffer with the private key

The connection URL must have the "wss://" protocol prefix.
This will verify that the server's certificate is signed by the given CA and present a client certificate to the server for client authentication.